# How to include javascript in extjs's view form

Tags: javascript, extjs, view, captcha

I am working in extjs. I want to generate captcha code in extjs form. So i am creating captcha code using javascript which is having code as-

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"            "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
     <title>BotBoot</title>

         <script type="text/javascript">
         var a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
         var b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
         var c = a + b
         function DrawBotBoot()
        {
         document.write("What is "+ a + " + " + b +"? ");
         document.write("<input id='BotBootInput' type='text' maxlength='2'    size='2'/>");
        }    
        function ValidBotBoot(){
        var d = document.getElementById('BotBootInput').value;
        if (d == c) return true;        
        return false;

     }
     </script>

     </head>
     <body>

      Are you human?<br />

       <script type="text/javascript">DrawBotBoot()</script>
       <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Check"  onclick="alert(ValidBotBoot());"/>

      </body>
      </html>
```

Its working correctly. But now i want to include this javascript captcha in my registration  form inside items block by mentioning xtype field. So how to include javascript in extjs view forms item element?

Comment: if you need more help you can ask!

Comment: Sir i had generated Captcha.js file with code as-"Ext.define('Balaee.view.sn.user.Captcha',{
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.captcha',
    initComponent: function(config){
        this.a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        this.b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
        this.c = this.a + this.b;
    },
DrawBotBoot: function(){
    },

    ValidBotBoot: function(){
    }
});" And in view form i had included xtype:captcha.But its not displaying anything. So what changes i need to do for displaying those a and b digits whose sum needs to do.Please help me sir

Comment: I've commented on my answer ;) Learn the basics about Ext.define and Ext.create.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a textfield and a button plus a custom class that looks something like this. If you implement it you can use it with `xtype: 'captcha'`

```
Ext.define('My.Captcha', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    alias: 'widget.captcha',

    initComponent: function(config){
        this.a = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);
        this.b = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10);       
        this.c = this.a + this.b;
    },

    DrawBotBoot: function(){
      //custom logic
    },

    ValidBotBoot: function(){
      //custom logic
    }
});
```

If you are going to use id's in your inputs you can use `Ext.getCmp()` to retrieve the components.
Good Luck

Comment: Thanx sir for reply.But how to use newly prepared captcha.js as xtype in view form's items? how to display these a and b in view form. In short,how to call above DrawBotBoot function for displaying two numbers? Actually i am very new to extjs. Can you please help me....

Comment: Yes I will. I think you first need to learn the basics about the class system in ExtJs [here](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/class_system) look @ `1.2) The New Way`. If you have more questions you can Ask a NEW question on SO :)

Comment: Thanx sir for helping me..I read the given documentation. But still not got answer of how to bring captcha's a and b on view form....

Comment: I can make a sample for you but now now. Do you want this?